# Событие 'fetch' в ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Интересует такой вопрос, срабатывает ли событие fetch в ServiceWorker при обращении к не-origin доменам? Или же можно обрабатывать обращения *только* на свой домен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceWorkers поддерживают кеширование с `no-origin` доменов, но нуждаются в отдельной настройке, и домен должен быть `https`

Для работы с ServiceWorkers рекомендую использовать [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) (пакет от Google). Такая реализация для кеширования картинок с Google Cloud:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /.*(?:googleapis|gstatic)\.com.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)/,
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'images',
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но меня интересует не столько возможность кэширования, сколько проксирование. И хотелось бы понять, все ли запросы попадают в SW по событию fetch, или только с origin домена

Comment: Если он настроен на прослушивание этих запросов, то да.